How to find out how much time did it take to display data in React app
There is React application with one route. I make several API requests to get data from backend. While fetching I show loading spinner and actual data after successful requests. I need to get time in milliseconds how much time did it take to get all files (like js files and so on), make requests and display data. How can I do that? I see there is Performance API but it seems to be deprecated.
I tried to use Performance API but it's deprecated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Absolutely! You can indeed use the getTime function to get the timestamp before and after making the API call to calculate the API response time.
  const startTime = new Date().getTime();
  fetch('your-api-endpoint')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const endTime = new Date().getTime();
    const apiResponseTime = endTime - startTime; 
    console.log("res:", apiResponseTime, "ms");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('err', error);
  });


This doesn't measure time spent rendering
